# Instant redicting and continue executing php script

Tags: php

When I use header() i got redicted after my srcipt has finised executing, same for include and even when I use html and put my php in there the iframe just works after php finished.

```
<?php 
header("Location: localhost/index.html");
sleep(120);
doSomethingUsefull();
?>
```

As sain before index.html is build after 120s.
Is there an other way I can include something, get redictet and my script continues executing?

Comment: Ideally, a well configured web server should not waste resources trying to complete a request for a client that has long disconnected. I'm pretty sure that you'll get more useful answers if you explain your end need (rather than just the solution you've figured out).

Comment: maybe try [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) function?

Comment: well it dont waste resources and to be hoonest i want my client to disconect, so i try to redict him! Edit: im alredy using ignore_user_abort

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain correctly. From the web server point of view, the whole purpose of handling an HTTP request is sending an answer back. I wasn't despising your script! Long running tasks are usually handled with cron jobs and/or queue systems.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<?php 
    header("Location: localhost/index.html");

    session_write_close();
    fastcgi_finish_request();

    sleep(120);
    doSomethingUsefull();
?>
```

Comment: is it possible to add "--enable-fpm" to config by the script? I'm actually not sure how i can enable fpm because i cant find the configure line as mentioned here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.install.php Edit: got it:  ini_set("--enable-fpm",1);

Comment: Did you get it working? It's hard to figure out what you need to do without knowing what you have for a setup. You need to get PHP and your web server to communicate via FPM.

Comment: haha well you are right, i dont know what im doing, i dont got it with ini_set("--enable-fpm",1); i just have done something wrong so taht it seems to work  :(  Have you got any good links where i can get the information I need?